# Report foreign travel during job transition? (Security Clearance)

Tags: new-job, united-states, travel, security-clearance

I am currently working for company (A) where I am required to hold security clearance. I have received an offer with another company (B) that also requires a clearance. Between my two jobs, I am planning to take few weeks to travel with my family.

How do I go about reporting my foreign travel during period between jobs? While I was working with company A, I typically reported my intended travel before the trip and later had debriefing with FSO or other security personal after I am back.

How do I do this process while I am changing jobs? Do I report to company A's FSO all my intended travel during those two weeks? How would I go about doing debriefing once I am back?

Comment: When you say Between jobs, you mean you will already have ceased your relationship with A, but not yet started with B?

Comment: If @DarkCygnus has guessed correctly, then I think the answer is most likely: tell FSO at company B. But it seems like in general this question would be better directed to whichever party is actually your employer at the point in time when you're traveling, or immediately thereafter if you're unemployed during the travel time.

Comment: Here is example to clarify. My last with company A is August 20th -- and my start day with company B is September 10th. Between those days I am traveling outside of US.

Comment: So, you already (or are about to) sign a contract with company B?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You should report to both companies.**

As a security clearance holder, your responsibility to report foreign travel is to *the government*, not to a particular company. Your company's security officer is just who you work through to report anything you need to.

Depending on your clearance, you are usually required to report planned foreign travel before the trip occurs. Go through whatever process you normally would with Company A to report that trip, and possibly note that this will occur after you have left the company.

Also report your foreign travel to Company B when you start after your trip. There's a good chance what you told Company A might not make it to Company B, and you want to make sure it's on your record there too. You will probably have to meet with a security officer on your first day and fill out a bunch of forms, so there should be a natural opportunity to bring this up.

Now, you probably don't *need* to report this to both companies, but this is the kind of thing where it's better to over-report than under-report. This way you've covered yourself on both ends and don't have to worry about someone saying you didn't tell the right person.